# simple Greatest divisor problem c++ implementation throws Time-Limit Exceeded

Tags: c++, arithmetic-expressions

I am submitting code to my university's tester, the code for me works thoroughly for the the test cases I provided.

The checker throws Time-Limit Exceeded error, I am testing in visual studio, and that's exactly compatible with the online judge compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int i, n, gd; cin >> n;
    gd = 1;
    if (n > 1) {
        for (i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                gd = i;
            }
        }
        cout << gd;
    }

    return 0;
}
}
```

I can't find why it throws such error. Thanks

The code just works in my visual studio, but can't pass the test. The checker hides test cases by the way.

Comment: If the code works correctly, and you only want to increase its performance, consider asking on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of SO. "_I can't find why it throws such error._" Typically, an automated checking system shows this error, if execution, of your code took longer, that maximum allowed time.

Comment: `std::gcd` could be helpful if you're not forbidden to use the standard library.

Comment: Find the smallest divisor, then divide `n` by it to get the largest. It will be significantly faster. You can stop the loop when you find the first divisor, or you get to sqrt(n).

Comment: @interjay For even `n` the answer is `n/2`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin True, but there's no need to special-case this. The smallest divisor in this case is 2 so the largest is n/2.

Comment: @interjay You are totally right.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the greatest divisor, look for the smallest divisor `d` (where `d > 1`). The greatest divisor is then `n/d`.

You can do this with a simple loop like you have which `break`s when it finds the first divisor. The loop can stop when it passes `sqrt(n)`, in which case the number is prime.

This is faster in the worst-case because it limits the number of iterations to sqrt(n). And in common cases where `d` is small, it will take a very small number of operations.

Comment: @Papa The loop will run from 2 to sqrt(n). In the case of n=3, sqrt(n) is less than 2 so the loop will do nothing.